# Why is my assert.areequal failing when the debugger says they are equal?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

This unit test should be passing and I can't figure out why it's not. The code works in my main controller, so I know it does work.  But I feel like it's assessing differently in my unit test.

I have tried various other asserts, with the exception of the false Booleans.  I don't want a false comparison.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DownloadFileNames()
    {
        // Arrange
        string ftpBase = "myfiles.com/public/doc";
        string fileName = "10408c";

        Search model = new Search();
        model.FileName = fileName;

        //A string to hold the base FTP address:
        Search searchResults = new Search();
        List<string> fnl = new List<string>();
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();

        // Act
        uriBuilder.Scheme = "ftp";
        uriBuilder.Host = ftpBase;

        FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.Uri);
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            files.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        reader.Close();
        responseStream.Dispose();

        //Loop through the resulting file names.
        foreach (string folder in files)
        {

            if (folder.IndexOf(".") < 1)
            {
                var childDirectory = uriBuilder.Uri + folder + "/";
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(childDirectory);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                responseStream.Dispose();

                searchResults.Messages = result;

                if (result.Contains(model.FileName))
                {

                    if (!model.FileName.Contains(".dat"))
                    {
                        model.FileName = model.FileName.Replace(".dat", "");

                        fnl.Add(ftpBase.Replace(ftpBase, uriBuilder.Uri + folder + "/") + model.FileName + ".dat");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fnl.Add(ftpBase.Replace(ftpBase, uriBuilder.Uri + folder + "/") + model.FileName);
                    }
                    //UpdateFile(fnl);

                    searchResults.Messages = "file found";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    searchResults.Messages = "file not found";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //searchResults.Messages = "Just Files";
            }
        }

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(fnl, "ftp://myfiles.com/public/doc/cor/10408c.dat");

    }
```

I expect the fnl and the string to match.  But the Expected gives this code instead.

"Expected:. "

I suspect I am missing something, but since I am still green on unit testing, I have no idea what it is I am missing.

If you have nothing constructive to say, please just pass on any remarks.  I have looked for answers to my question, but nothing I found seemed to relate to my issue enough to be of any help.

Comment: `fnl` is a string list (ie: `List<string>`) while the other is just a raw `String`

Comment: There is no way those two completely different objects will match given the shown code.

Comment: So I need to make the List<string> into a string?  Any idea on how to do that and the rest of the code still work?

Comment: Well assuming that the list contains only one string then just use the index `Assert.AreEqual(fnl[0], "ftp://myfiles.com/public/doc/cor/10408c.dat");`

Comment: Thank you very much.  I see now that should have been my answer.  It is a list/array after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fnl` is a string list (ie: `List<string>`) while the other is just a raw `String`

There is no way those two completely different objects will match given the shown code

Assuming that the list contains only one string then just use the index from the list

```
//...

Assert.AreEqual(fnl[0], "ftp://myfiles.com/public/doc/cor/10408c.dat");
```

And just for readability

```
//...

string expected = "ftp://myfiles.com/public/doc/cor/10408c.dat";
string actual = fnl[0];

Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```